# What is the uppercase file?

Tags: windows, ntfs, chkdsk

I ran a chkdsk and it stated it was correcting the uppercase file. Out of complete curiosity I Googled it but couldn't find any info. Anyone know what this file is?

Comment: For searchability: I got these error lines: `Read-only chkdsk found bad on-disk uppercase table - using system table.` / `Errors detected in the uppercase file.` (without `/f`), and `Correcting errors in the uppercase file.` (with `/f`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stores a mapping between lower-case letters and upper-case letters (so as to provide case-insensitivity).  Details here: http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/16/353873.aspx

And this one may apply more specifically to you: http://www.siao2.com/2007/12/27/6875879.aspx, and links to this MSKB article: [Error message when you run Chkdsk.exe on a Windows XP-based or on a Windows Server 2003-based computer: “Correcting errors in the uppercase file”](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940830)

Comment: Perfect :) I figured it was something like that, but it's nice to quench my curiosity.